# Explicit line spacing in revtex 4

Tags: line-spacing, revtex

I am required to use 13pt line spacing for a report and want to use revtex 4 as document class. However, I am not able to set the line spacing explicitly.

Comment: Are you using the most recent version: `revtex4-1`? Also, you want to keep the regular font size, but just change the spacing or `\baselineskip`?

Comment: I am currently using font size 11pt with the optional argument `tightenlines` and `revtex4` because `revtex4-1` conflicts with the `algorithmic` package on my machine.

Comment: If you are preparing a document for publication, then I suggest moving to `revtex4-1` and finding an alternative to `algorithmic`. Quick tests have shown that `algorithmicx` works, although probably not in an algorithm environment. It should be trivial to use the `float` package to bootstrap one though. If you are not preparing a document for journal publication, then I recommend avoiding REVTeX altogether because problems like this will really plague you.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. The current version is not for publication (hence the odd restrictions) but the document will eventually be published such that I am trying to stick to revtex to minimise the overhead. Trying `\baselineskip` didn't work for the `revtex4-1` document though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that `revtex4` uses a definition of `\normalsize` equal to that of the standard classes, namely, a line spacing of 13.6pt for the `11pt` font size option. If you only want to change the line spacing of `\normalsize`, you may use the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch this command (replace "13.6" with "13"). If you want to change the line spacing of all font size commands, use `\linespread{0.956}` (13/13.6).

```
\documentclass[11pt,tightenlines]{revtex4}

% Alternative A
% \usepackage{etoolbox}
% \patchcmd{\normalsize}{13.6}{13}{}{}

% Alternative B
\linespread{0.956}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd go with `\linespread` that will proportionally affect all other sizes.

Comment: @egreg On second thought, I'd go with it, too. :-)